# Generating unique id in J2ME

Tags: java-me, registration, uuid, mac-address, imei

I want to generate universally unique id for registration process of my j2me application. i came across following approaches for that

1. IMEI no of device [Getting IMEI and IMSI in Java ME](http://goo.gl/lQVT5) this approach doesn't work on most of devices. Problem with IMEI is is not that easy to get it from Midlet for most of models.
2. Bluetooth device address [Getting Bluetooth Address](http://goo.gl/8VgOZ)
     Problem Needs support for Bluetooth API and will limit no of devices app can run on.
3. UUID class
     Problem Need Bluetooth API as it is in javax.bluetooth package same prob

The registration process used by my company for their android app is as follows

1. customer mobile will send IMEI no and Token provided by company to server using SMS
2. Server will send licence key to customer mobile which will be stored in customer mobile

And i have to follow the same approach for j2me application

One solution can be getting unique id from server through SMS. but company uses above registration process.

Is there any other approch that i can use for registraing my application or is there any way to overcome above problems.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @funkybro that a Jad key with a unique ID provided by the server would solve the issue. But if its not possible I would create an id based on mobile time and a hash code.

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
StringBuffer id = new StringBuffer(Long.toString(time, 16).toUpperCase());
id.append(Integer.toHexString(new Object().hashCode()).toUpperCase());
```

If this id is duplicated the registration process fails and the application is asked for a new id.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a server generated unique ID in the jad at deploy time.